# How to make Qt Plugin project inside a Qt App project

Tags: c++, qt, qml

When I run my application, QtCreator always show an error like this

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "SampleModules" is not installed
```

I tried
- search for solutions everywhere
- move qmldir file to application project or binary folder
- change plugin
- update .pro file with many ways (even add link to resource file of plugins)

My full source code is in here, I put it to github for everyone to have a whole view of my code, it just a quick sample.
    https://github.com/chaunnt/QtWithQMLPluginProjects

Here some details
My project.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

    SUBDIRS += \
        SampleModules \
        SampleApp


    SampleApp.depends = SampleModules
```

My module.pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = SampleModules
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += plugin c++11

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = SampleModules
version = 1.0
# Input
SOURCES +=         samplemodules_plugin.cpp         samplemodules.cpp

HEADERS +=         samplemodules_plugin.h         samplemodules.h

DISTFILES = qmldir

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) "$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)"     "$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}
```

my app.pro

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH =

QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

I expect to make a Qt Plugin project which can register C++, QML,     Singleton QML for my Qt App project.

my qmldir file

```
module SampleModules
plugin SampleModules
classname SampleModulesPlugin
typeinfo plugins.qmltypes
```

Comment: You should add relevant details directly to question, because links break, but questions here should stay useful. .pro files and current directory structure should be good. Also check what is [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself.
add this line to main.cpp

```
engine.addImportPath("..");
```

Root cause is because the SampleApp binary can not find the folder of QML in output directory.

It is searching for folder

```
"Output/SampleApp/SampleModule"
```

but we are outputing projects as

```
"Output/SampleApp"
"Output/SampleModule"
```

NOTE: add env variable QML_IMPORT_TRACE = 1 in Build & Run environments variables in QtCreator to get which plugins is loaded and what is wrong.

I also push the fixed patch on my github for template project